# What is $O\Big((n+1)!\Big)$?

Tags: asymptotics

What is $f(n) = (n+1)!$ which is also $f(n) = (n+1)n!$ in terms of big-O notation?
My guess is $O(n \cdot n!)$ but I am not sure. I only know it is certainly $f(n) \in O(n^n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stirling expansion for $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi}(\frac{n}{e})^{n} n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ your expression is $n!n +O(n!)$. Hence $(n+1)! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi} n^{n+\frac{3}{2}} e^{-n} +O(n!)$

Comment: You're missing the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ from Stirling's formula.

Comment: That's why I used the $\sim$, not the $=$ sign

Comment: But $\sim$ [does not ignore constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition).  Saying "$n! \sim (n/e)^n \sqrt{n}$" is saying that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n/e)^n \sqrt{n}} = 1,$$ which isn't true.  It is true however that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}} = 1,$$ so $n! \sim (n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$.